# Can't access Github in Browser and WSL (Connection Refused!)

Tags: windows, github, networking, connection-refused

I encountered an issue on my Windows 10 22H2 PC where I am unable to access GitHub and showing “ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.” when using Microsoft Edge, Chrome, and Brave browsers. Strangely, other websites like Google, Instagram, and Twitter work perfectly fine. Here are the steps I’ve taken so far to troubleshoot the problem:

- VPN Attempts:
  I tried using both Proton VPN and Psiphon VPN to see if the issue was related to my network configuration. Unfortunately, this did not resolve the problem.
- DNS Flushing and Changes:
  I flushed the DNS cache and experimented with different DNS servers (including Cloudflare and Google), but GitHub remains inaccessible.
- Network Settings Reset:
  As a last resort, I reset my entire Windows 10 network settings, hoping it would fix the issue. However, GitHub still refuses to load.
- WSL:
  To rule out browser-specific issues, I tried to clone a repository in my Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) KALI Distro. Unfortunately, the error persists even in WSL.

When I ping the GitHub IP address, it responds without any issues.

Additional Information:

Antivirus or security software is not causing the problem.

I appreciate any insights or solutions to help resolve this GitHub access issue.
Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you open cmd or Powershell, and try `curl https://github.com` or `curl --insecure https://github.com` ? Also, what is your machine's local time and timezone? This might sound strange, but I've had issues with downloading things from Google Drive when my machine's time wasn't matching the expected time for my timezone (my Windows time was deliberately set to +1h). As the third thing to try - check your `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file, and see if there's an entry for github.com.

Comment: PS C:\Users\nanda> curl https://github.com
curl : Unable to connect to the remote server.  my time zone is (UTC +5:30) Chennai, Kolkata, New Delhi. and there is GitHub in the host file

Comment: Also I encountered the same issue with some of the url given in the host file like mediafire, mega, telegraph, cheater.

Comment: I solved the problem by deleting the host file bro. thanks a lot for helping!